# Как распарсить такой JSON из ВК

Tags: java, android, json, vkontakte-api

Имеется такой JSON ответ

```
{
  response: {
    count: 19,
    items: [
      {
        id: 158,
        title: 'Челябинск',
        important: 1
      },
      {
        id: 88,
        title: 'Набережные Челны',
        important: 1
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Москва',
        important: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Санкт-Петербург',
        important: 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь распарсить вот так,

```
try {
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.responseString);
  JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("items");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
    City city = new City();
    String title = item.getString("title");
    int id = item.getInt("id");
    city.setTitle(title);
    city.setId(id);
    Log.d("VkParseLog", city.getTitle());
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Но получаю вот это:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for items
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
    at ru.bullfinchdev.vkgram.SearchParamActivity$CitiesGet$1.onComplete(SearchParamActivity.java:92)
    at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest$3.run(VKRequest.java:482)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Массив `"items"` находится внутри объекта `"response"`, а вы пытаетесь получить его у корневого объекта.

```
try {
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.responseString);
  JSONObject responseObject = object.getJSONObject("response");
  JSONArray array = responseObject.getJSONArray("items");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
    City city = new City();
    String title = item.getString("title");
    int id = item.getInt("id");
    city.setTitle(title);
    city.setId(id);
    Log.d("VkParseLog", city.getTitle());
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("items");
```

на

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray("items");
```

замените